# Inserting MySQL data from PHP API

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

I am creating an API in PHP and I am stuck at a point where I need same data of one table into another.

In table one, the order ID is created by auto increment. I want to copy its order ID into the 2nd table order ID:

[image]

So a customer can add multiple items in same order:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly. Are you asking how you can move data between two tables? Because if that's so, it's quite simple to do:

Let's suppose you want to move a record from table `foo` to table `bar`, you can use the query:

```
INSERT INTO `bar` (SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE id = $some_id)
```

Where `$some_id` is the ID of the record you want to move.

But again, your question wasn't very clear, so apologies if this isn't what you were trying to do.